# How to add libs from Maven Central etc. to an existing non-Gradle, non-Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, gradle, dependency-management

I want to be able to use Gradle (or something like it) to download, add & manage 3rd party libs from Maven Central etc. but without having to build (compile) my project with Gradle. (It's an Eclipse GWT app, and I believe I need to keep my existing Eclipse GWT plugin build process to keep the code hotswap functionality).

I want the jars to go into my "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" directory and be added to my build path so I can start using the libs straight away, even though it's not a "Gradle project".

Is this possible? If so how?

(I've tried adding build.gradle to my project root, adding dependencies and then calling "gradle build" from command line. It says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" (but obviously .jars aren't added to my project's classpath etc.), but that's as far as I've gotten so far, and I'm not sure I'm on the right track. When I try right-clicking the project and calling Gradle > Tasks Quick Launcher, it says "Selected project is not a Gradle project").

Answer (score 0):

What You want to achieve is possible but *definitely* not how gradle should be used. You should use gradle [war](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) plugin (or maybe there exists any plugin for `GWT` projects - the chance is very high), but because I don't know how (and if) it integrates seamlessly with `GWT`, eclipse-managed project I wouldn't recommend it. 
Fortunately gradle is very flexible system and it can be done without applying any plugin.

The following script is just a proof of concept but can be easily extended:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    eclipse 
    eclipseRt
}

dependencies {
    eclipse 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'       
    eclipseRt 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

task copyToWebInfLib(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.eclipse
    into 'WEB-INF/lib'
}

task modifyEclispeClasspath << {
    //here add dependencies from *both* configurations
    //to eclipse classpath
}
```

Explanation:

First of all You need to add appropriate *repositories* where the desired dependencies are kept. You can add multiple repositories.

Then You need to define two *configurations* (configuration is basically a name for a dependency set). Why two? Because You need to provide dependencies that are required both for development and to be copied into `WEB-INF/lib` (such as guava) and only for development (such as servlet api - which is provided by servlet container). `War` plugin mentioned above handles this for You (*providedCompile* and *providedRuntime* configurations) but here You need to create configurations by yourself. You can change the names later on.

Now comes *dependencies* block. Here You declare the dependencies You use in project but remember to mark them with appropriate configuration name.

Finally You need a task (of type `Copy`) to resolve dependencies - only those marked with *eclipse* (configuration name) will be copied into `WEB-INF/lib` folder. And a second task to modify appropriate eclipse configuration files. Since I don't work with eclipse on a daily basis I don't know how to modify the files. But You just need to know the format and probably add appropriate lines using `XmlSlurper` e.g. (AFAIK eclipse files are kept in XML format).

In general this is it. Feel free to ask additional questions. It also good idea to use [gradle wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) but this is an additional step.

Comment: Is that what You were looking for?

Comment: Yes, kind of. I guess I would need to check my classpath for if the entry already exists, and delete older versions etc. So I'm presuming there's nothing automatic in Gradle for this?

Comment: There's an eclipse plugin but I'm not sure if it works with GWT projects, I suppose not. What I've prepared is in fact semi-automatic solution. You can remove all the dependencies from classpath and prepare them with gradle.

Comment: Yes but my project has some dependency jars that I added manually (since they are not published on Maven Central etc., & some aren't even on the internet). Maybe I can use the "local file" option in Gradle, if there is one, to manage those, then I can remove all & rewrite the entries as you suggest. I'll look it up.

Comment: Yes, there's such option. E.g.: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Answer (score 0):

The [download-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22download-maven-plugin%22) is [*"Meant to be used from anywhere on the system to download an artifact at a specific location. Does not need a pom file to be run and can be used directly from the command line."*](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin).